# Add Extra Actions to LinkTo in Octane

Tags: ember.js

I have a dropdown menu with links, when the links are clicked I'd like the menu to close.

Something like (a11y/i18n truncated):

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <LinkTo @route="myprofile">
            Profile
        </LinkTo>
    </li>
    <li>
        <LinkTo @route="logout">
            Logout
        </LinkTo>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to add an additional click handler to the link to, something like:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <LinkTo @route="myprofile" {{on "click" this.closeMenu}}>
            Profile
        </LinkTo>
    </li>
    <li>
        <LinkTo @route="logout" {{on "click" this.closeMenu}}>
            Logout
        </LinkTo>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However this makes the `LinkTo` useless as it reloads the page as if following a link instead of transitioning to a new route. We're currently doing this using [hember-link-action](https://github.com/Kuzirashi/ember-link-action), but I'd love to find a more idiomatic way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a component to mostly handle this, but I'm quite certain there are more edge cases in `LinkTo` then I've covered (for example it doesn't cover a passed model or list of models).  I called this `<LinkToWithAction />` and it looks like:

```
<a href={{this.href}} class={{if this.isActive "active"}} {{on "click" this.navigate}} >
    {{yield}}
</a>
```

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class LinkToWithActionComponent extends Component {
  @service router;

  get href() {
    return this.router.urlFor(this.args.route, {
      queryParams: this.queryParams,
    });
  }

  get isActive() {
    return this.router.isActive(this.args.route);
  }

  get queryParams() {
    return this.args.queryParams ?? {};
  }

  @action
  navigate(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.args.action();
    this.router.transitionTo(this.args.route, {
      queryParams: this.queryParams,
    });
  }
}
```

and it is called as:

```
<LinkToWithAction
  @route="mymaterials"
  @action={{set this.isOpen false}}
  @queryParams={{hash course=null}}
>
  {{t "general.myprofile"}}
</LinkToWithAction>
```

This is made more annoying by this [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/19493) with `transitionTo` that adds unset queryParams to the URL when called which effects the public router service. The built in component uses the private internal router where this behavior doesn't exist, and it may be worth using that private service, but for now we're going to live with passing the query params.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to perform additional logic, you may implement redirect in an action instead of using the `LinkTo` helper. To do so, you need to inject `RouterService` into your component and then call its `transitionTo` method. Something like:

```js
export default class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  @service router;

  @action
  navigate(route) {
    this.menuExpanded = false;
    this.router.transitionTo(route);
  }
}
```

Note that there also exist the `transitionTo()` method from Route and `transitionToRoute()` from Controller that behave like the `LinkTo` helper. But those methods are deprecated now, and using `RouterService` is a [recommended](https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v3.x/#toc_routing-transition-methods) idiomatic way of doing transitions in js code.

Comment: This would handle the navigation piece, but that isn't all LinkTo does. It also creates a semantically correct `a` tag with a valid `href` pointing to the route along with adding some classes if the current route is the active one and preventing transition in that case. This is a good start, but I'm hoping to get everything `LinkTo` along with a little bit more.